# Date not decoded for sorting (so used as string) with datatable moment-with-locale

Tags: javascript, datatables, momentjs

I am trying to use moment plugin for Datatable with local french. And it is not working, the date field is not sorted as a date but as a string.
What I see in the javaconsole is that in the fnSort function of Datatable, the aSortData of each element inside aoData remains "17 février 2016 10:02:29" instead of being transformed into the associated integer.
I have first tried with a local c opy of the different javascript files then using the network version but in fails in both cases.

Here is my javascript code

```
<script src="./my_files/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'D MMMM YYYY hh:mm:ss', 'fr');
        $('#data-table-logs').DataTable();  
    }); 
</script>
```

and here are example of data in my table.

```
<tbody>

    <tr>
        <td>17 février 2016 10:02:29</td>
        <td>5111</td>
        <td>Jeromrm ghhh</td>
        <td>Entrant</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>10 février 2016 12:02:10</td>
        <td>5111</td>
        <td>Jeromrm ghhh</td>
        <td>Entrant</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>27 janvier 2016 16:01:17</td>
        <td>5111</td>
        <td>Jeromrm ghhh</td>
        <td>Entrant</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td>19 mai 2016 16:05:53</td>
        <td>5411</td>
        <td>jdsn Reference</td>
        <td>Sortant</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>30 mars 2016 14:03:06</td>
        <td>5111</td>
        <td>Jeromrm ghhh</td>
        <td>Sortant</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>14 mars 2016 12:03:27</td>
        <td>5111</td>
        <td>Jeromrm ghhh</td>
        <td>Sortant</td>
    </tr>
```

It seems to me that I have fully followed the procedure from https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18 except that I have used moment-with-locale instead of moment.

Does anyone has an idea on this?

Here is the full html

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>My Site</title>


    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function () {
            $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'D MMMM YYYY hh:mm:ss', 'fr');
            $('#data-table-logs').DataTable();  
        }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body class="">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="main-content">   
            <div class="row">
                <div id="main-content-block" class="col-xs-12">

                    <div>
                        <table class="display" id="data-table-logs">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Durée de l'appel</th>
                                    <th>Autre partie</th>
                                    <th>Nom</th>
                                    <th>Type d'appel</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>17 février 2016 10:02:29</td>
                                    <td>5111</td>
                                    <td>Jeromrm ghhh</td>
                                    <td>Entrant</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>10 février 2016 12:02:10</td>
                                    <td>5111</td>
                                    <td>Jeromrm ghhh</td>
                                    <td>Entrant</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>27 janvier 2016 16:01:17</td>
                                    <td>5111</td>
                                    <td>Jeromrm ghhh</td>
                                    <td>Entrant</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>19 mai 2016 16:05:53</td>
                                    <td>5411</td>
                                    <td>jdsn Reference</td>
                                    <td>Sortant</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>30 mars 2016 14:03:06</td>
                                    <td>5111</td>
                                    <td>Jeromrm ghhh</td>
                                    <td>Sortant</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>14 mars 2016 12:03:27</td>
                                    <td>5111</td>
                                    <td>Jeromrm ghhh</td>
                                    <td>Sortant</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>19 février 2016 18:02:31</td>
                                    <td>5111</td>
                                    <td>Jeromrm ghhh</td>
                                    <td>Sortant</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thank in advance,
Olivier

Comment: please provide the full <table> and valid html, see https://validator.w3.org/check

Comment: Here is the full html (where I have removed all useless code for this issue, the page is originally generated with Django and I saved it as local with Chrome).:

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, all values must be parsable by the format provided.  You've made one simple mistake, which is that you have `hh` (hours of a 12-hour clock) instead of `HH` (hours of a 24-hour clock).  Since the data contains hours greater than 12, it doesn't match, and thus the whole column is treated as a string.

Simply change your script from:

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment( 'D MMMM YYYY hh:mm:ss', 'fr');
```

To:

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment( 'D MMMM YYYY HH:mm:ss', 'fr');
```

See also, the [working jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/6ubur9w5/).